# Pascal function is looped

Tags: function, reverse, pascal, freepascal

Why this code doesn't work?

When I execute, windows stops it, becouse is probably looped and stoped working.

```
function revstr(a:string):string;
  var out_s:string;
  ls,i:integer;

  begin
    ls:=11;

    for i:=1 to ls do
      out_s:=out_s+a[ls-i+1];

    revstr:=out_s; 
  end;
```

Comment: I a is not transfered well, becouse when i write out a, in a are different signs, not word...

Answer (score 3):

Your temporary output string, out_s, is never initialised. Also, you seem to be assuming that the length of the input string is 11 characters. What happens if it's only 10 characters long? Then you would be accessing an element which doesn't exist.

Not that matters but the 'ls' variable in unnecessary. Either make it a constant or else use the naked value 11 in your code.

It would be better to write the function as follows:

```
Function Reverse (const a: string): string;
var
 i: integer;

begin
 result:= '';
 for i:= length (a) downto 1 do
  result:= result + a[i]
end;
```

An alternative way is shown below. This code would be quicker as there is no string concatenation but it's not too intuitive and may work only in Delphi.

```
Function Reverse (const a: string): string;
var
 i, j: integer;
 P: PChar;

begin
 SetLength (Result, Length (a));
 P:= Pchar (Result);
 j:= 0;
 for i:= length (a) downto 1 do
  begin
   p[j]:= a[i];
   inc (j)
  end; 
 end;
```